# Fusio api cache configuration

Tags: php, doctrine

Googled and tried,but failed.

How to configure [Fusio](http://fusio-project.org/) to use redis.?

```
//'psx_cache_factory'       => null,
```

This doesnt work:

```
 'psx_cache_factory'       => 'redis'
```

This also doesnt work:

```
'psx_cache_factory'       => 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379',
```

Comment: please help me on [Fusio authentication fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47028566/fusio-authentication-failed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by developer.

[Github](https://github.com/apioo/fusio/issues/61)

```
'psx_cache_factory'       => function($config, $namespace){
    $client = new \Predis\Client([
        'scheme' => 'tcp',
        'host'   => '10.0.0.1',
        'port'   => 6379,
    ]);

    return new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\PredisCache($client);
},
```